# GMAPS : OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error without exceeding the quotas

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

We have this issue with GMaps :
when we first open our page (with a points over a gmap) we have those errors and the map dont show :
[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgz26.png)

then if we reload the page the map is shown correctly but with this error in the console :
DIRECTIONS_ROUTE: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: There was an issue performing a Directions request.

i've checked our quotas usage and we are at :
[quotas below the limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAYf0.png)

what do you think is the problem ?
how can i check my QPS usage ?